# Polynomial: Find x given y

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, cubics

I've been given a cubic polynomial, with values a, b, c, and d, and have been asked to find the point x given a y value.

I can factor the function easily enough, but I do not know how to isolate x algebraically given y.

Comment: Can you tell us what the polynomial is?

Comment: It is a question on an assignment so I do not want to give the polynomial.

Comment: Do you have the values for a,b,c,d ?

Comment: @kennyB Yes, I have a,b, c, and d

Comment: I think the answer is subtract the y value from the polynomial and then solve for the roots. Not sure why this works, but the local maximum became the x intercept.

Comment: If you have a,b,c,d then it's a simple substitution problem. Assuming that your function is y = ax^3 +bx^2+cx+d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it sounds like you are trying to solve
$$p(x) = C$$
where $p(x)$ is a cubic function, and $C$ is a given constant.

You say that you know how to factor $p(x)$.  That's good -- but it's actually not particularly helpful in this case, as it doesn't help you get to a solution.

Instead, rewrite the equation as
$$p(x) - C = 0$$
and see if you can factor *the new polynomial that appears on the left-hand side*.  If you can factor *it*, you can easily find the zeroes of $p(x)-C$, which are then the solutions of your equation.